# How to specify single qoute in string builder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having a code like

```
 var scriptBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 scriptBuilder.Append(@"
        like_string = frm.like.value.replace(/'/gi,""''"");
```

while running, the script is like,

```
 like_string = frm.like.value.replace(/&apos;/gi,"&apos;&apos;");
```

i tried it by putting someother characters. But it showing error like

```
( Excepted
```

can any one tell me how to specify the single quote in this string bulider??

Comment: Where are you putting this code? "This is ASP.NET" doesn't really explain anything. Using `scriptBuilder.Append(@"like_string = frm.like.value.replace(/'/gi,""''"")");` works fine in a console app, so you are clearly running the code in some other way than in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `)` charecter.
change code to `scriptBuilder.Append(@"
        like_string = frm.like.value.replace(/'/gi,""''""));`

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout the bellow sample

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Declare object

sb.Append("Text before quote");
sb.Append("'"); 
sb.Append("Text after quote"); 
sb.Append("'");

sb.ToString(); // Final output
```

Comment: ya i actually tried this first, but it showing lots of errors like ,'{ missing','\invalid expressions term' and so on.

Comment: Can you just simply write a console application and tryout the sample code given above? Its works fine without any issue.